# How to do Ctrl+Alt+Del via Logitech iPad keyboard

Tags: keyboard, parallels-desktop

This is and old question, but all the answers I managed to find in the Internet didn't solved my issue.

I am using a Logitech wireless keyboard on my iPad --- "Logitech Ultrathin Keyboard Cover" to be more precise.

I use Parallels on my iPad to access my Windows 7 computer.

When I go into it, I am asked to press Ctrl+Alt+Del to start a session. I am not allowed to disable that option on my Windows computer.

I have tried all the keyboard combinations, but nothing seems to work. How can I press Ctrl+Alt+Del on my wireless keyboard???

Comment: Normally `Fn` + `Backspace` = `Del`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

If it's Parallels Mobile, you need to use the on-screen keyboard for complex keyboard commands such as this one. According to the documentation, once you bring up the on-screen keyboard, there are arrow keys on the top of the keyboard to switch to a "function" keyboard; from there, you can press "delete" with both the Ctrl and Alt modifiers active.

The Mobile Guide ([link](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v7/ga-locales/documentation/en_US/Parallels%20Mobile%20User%27s%20Guide.pdf)) produced by Parallels for this application can help guide you further. (the Page 19 area references the items I mention above)

Answer (score 1):

Hold the Command key down on your keyboard for 2-3 seconds until the keyboard shortcut window appears. It's likely that the developers of your app have enabled a keyboard shortcut to allow this to work -- however, this is app-dependent and would not be determined by iOS or Windows, but rather Parallels. Holding the Command key will allow you to see whether a shortcut has been assigned to produce Ctrl-Alt-Delete on the remote computer.